# What can I do to validate my code error

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

What can I do to make sure my code is secure? My add-on from Mozilla was validated, but apparently this line was unsecure:

```
if (p.getElementById("bluebarholder"))
  p.getElementById("top").setAttribute('onclick', 'window.open("http://www.facebook.com","_self")');
```

I don't know whats the issue or how to solve it as they haven't replied to my message yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of "eval is evil".
You're passing a string as an event handler, forcing the browser to fire up a Javascript parser to evaluate the string.

Instead, you should call `addEventListener` to add a function as a handler.

Comment: Thanks SLaks. I changed the attribute and is awaiting validation.

Comment: Hey SLaks just getting back to you to let you know your method worked after validation. TY